# function attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to use function attributes to set variable values as an alternate to using global variables.  But sometimes I assign another short name to a function.  The behavior seems to always do what I want, i.e. the value gets assigned to the function whether I use the long or short name, as shown below.  Is there any danger in this?

```
def flongname():
    pass

f = flongname
f.f1 = 10
flongname.f2 = 20
print flongname.f1, f.f2
```

And the last line returns `10 20` showing that the different function names refer to the same function object.  Right?

Answer (score 5):

`id` shows that the both `f` and `flongname` are references to the same object.

```
>>> def flongname():
...     pass
... 
>>> f = flongname
>>> id(f)
140419547609160
>>> id(flongname)
140419547609160
>>>
```

so yes- the behavior you're experiencing is expected.

Comment: the `id` built-in is indeed the correct way to show that the renamed function references the same object.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
f = flongname  # <- Now f has same id as flongname
f.f1 = 10 # <- a new entry is added to flongname.__dict__
flongname.f2 = 20 # <- a new entry is added to flongname.__dict__
print flongname.f1, f.f2 # Both are refering to same dictionary of the function
```

looking it as it is is doesn't seems dangerous, just remember nobody else is modifying its `dict`

```
In [40]: f.__dict__
Out[40]: {}

In [41]: flongname.__dict__
Out[41]: {}

In [42]: f.f1=10

In [43]: flongname.__dict__
Out[43]: {'f1': 10}

In [44]: f.__dict__
Out[44]: {'f1': 10}

In [45]: flongname.f2 = 20

In [46]: f.__dict__
Out[46]: {'f1': 10, 'f2': 20}
```

Comment: Good to know that this is where the attributes go, into the `dict`.  Thanks.